# Android Error when rotating phone after taking picture using Intent ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

Tags: android

I get error on ActivityResult:

> "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getPath()' on a null object reference",

when take the picture then rotate the phone or emulator then confirm "save" picture.

This is how I call the camera:

```
File file = getOutputMediaFile(processid);
            picUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

            Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, picUri); 
            startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

Comment: Post your code for onActivityResult() and the stack trace that includes the error.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code for `onActivityResult()`, I can only make an experienced guess at the problem. There are many different camera apps and they don't all behave the same way.

Typically, when you request camera image capture and provide the `Uri` for the image with `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, the image is written to that `Uri` and no `Uri` is returned in the result intent.  I suspect that in your `onActivityResult()`, you are expecting the result intent to contain a `Uri`.  It has none: `resultIntent.getData()` is null.

If you do *not* provide an `Uri` for the image in your request intent with `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, then the result intent *does* contain an `Uri`, usually for a thumbnail size image.

Comment: I have this            String filepath = picUri.getPath();

                            Bitmap bmp = fromGallery(filepath, targetW, targetH);

                            imgPhoto.setImageBitmap(bmp);

Comment: Post your code for `onActivityResult()` and the stack trace that includes the error.

Comment: Please re-read my answer.  When `onActivityResult()` is called, `picUri` is null.  The image is stored at the `Uri` you included in your Intent with EXTRA_OUTPUT.  If you are setting `picUri' from the result Intent in  `onActivityResult()` it will be null.  If `picUri` is the same object you used when you called `startActivityForResult()`, it no longer has the original value and is now null.

Comment: When i don't rotate the device after taking the picture everything works fine. I do this to replicate the error:

Comment: Where is `picUri` defined?  Is it a member of your Activity class?  If it is, you are not saving and restoring it correctly so that when the activity restarts after the configuration change caused by the rotation, `picUri` is null.